# Retrieve FirebaseUser data by UID using only FirebaseAuth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using the`FirebaseAuth` Flutter plugin in order to manage the authentication process of users in my app. So far, I have been able to retrieve data from the current user with no trouble. However, I would like to retrieve user information data such as the profile picture using the UID of that user. This is quite easy when the user I want to get the data from is the current user, but I can't see the way of doing that when the user is different.

Is it possible, in some way, to build an instance of `FirebaseUser` specifying the UID? Or am I forced to store that information in some external storage platform? I prefer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, getting user info from any user besides the current one has to be done in a managed environment like a server or [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You can use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) to handle this.